# TTS *and* Speech Input simultaneously?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I noticed that as soon as a voice recognition activity starts, text-to-speech output stops.

I understand the rational: TTS output could be "heard" by the voice recognition engine and interfere with its proper operation.

My question: Is this behavior hard-coded into the system, or can it be modified by a setting or parameter (in the API)?

Comment: when you use .speak(), are you flushing or queuing?

Comment: @Ian I am queuing: tts.speak("some text...", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Must the activity simultaneously use recognition and TTS? If the recognition can wait (functionally speaking), force the event to spawn the `RecognizerIntent` only [onUtteranceCompleted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html)

This is pure speculation, but there must be some common feature that can only be used by TTS and recognition one at a time (both apis come from android.speech.*)

Comment: it would be interesting to look at the source code of TTS and find any exception catches that would interrupt the utterance

Comment: Spawning RecognizerIntent onUtteranceCompleted() works well, but I now have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518963/audio-signal-when-voice-search-dialog-is-ready-to-accept-input Thanks +3.