# Wait for TTS/speech-recognition to complete in Android app

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice

I have many sections of code that utilize TTS and speech recognition. However when there are multiple tts in a row or multiple speech recognition in a row, it either crashes or skips them entirely. Sometimes it continues through code without waiting for recognition to complete, which will cause crashing and incorrect variables later on. How can I have my app pause and wait for completion? I have looked into wait, enumerator, sub routines but none seem to fix the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650973/speech-to-text-and-text-to-speech-at-same-timem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480573/tts-and-speech-input-simultaneously?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When using TTS, try extends `UtteranceProgressListener` (API level 15 or higher) on your TTS class. 
here [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) for  how to use that abstract class. That abstract class include 
     method `public void onDone(String utteranceId){}`
which will called when your speech complete.
for Speech recognition, if you used `RecognitionListener`, there is method `public void onResults (Bundle arg0)` which will called when speech recognition end and will give you a result.
So now u know when the TTS and Speech recognition complete. Just try make some code run inside TTS onDone() or Speech Recognition onResult. Hope this will help.