# Speech to text and Text to speech at same time

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm developing an app where I need to use booth SpeechRecognizer and TTS. But I'm facing some problems while trying this. The main one is that if I initialize TTS, SpeechRecgonizer seems not to work, and If I disable TTS, then SpeechRecognizer works fine. Next there is code snipet with the relevant code:

**CODE**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    private static TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        /*SPEECH RECOGNIZER INSTANT*/
        Log.d("SPEECH", "speech recognition available: " + SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechListener());

        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());

        /*START LISTENING*/
        mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

        /*CHECK TTS AVAILABLE*/
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction( TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA );
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CHECK_TTS_DATA: {
                /*IF OK, INITIALIZES TTS*/
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                    Log.d("TTS", "TTS available");
                    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("TTS", "TTS NOT available");
                    Intent promptInstall = new Intent();
                    promptInstall.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(promptInstall);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**OnInitListener implementation*/
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            /*set Language*/
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            /*STARTS MAIN METHOD*/
            Log.d("SPEECH", "Initialized, starting main method");
            SpeechWhenMotion();
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }
    }


    /**INNER LISTENER CLASS*/
    private class SpeechListener implements RecognitionListener {
        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onBufferReceived");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onError: " + error);
            mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onEvent");
        }
        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onPartialResults");
        }
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onReadyForSpeech");
        }
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onResult");

        matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onRmsChanged");
        }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }
        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onEndOfSpeech");
        }
    }
```

So basically what I'm facing is what explained in the introduction. If I don't do `tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);`, then I see in the LogCat the logs refering to the speech listener, but If I initialize the TTS I don't see this logs.

Also, I suppose that when I'm able to make them work, I should stop listening when TTS speaks.

**UPDATE -- COMPLETE SIMPLE PROJECT CODE**

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    /*Voice and speech variables*/
    private static TextToSpeech tts;

    public static final int CHECK_TTS_DATA = 1;

    public static boolean fase0 = true;
    public static boolean fase1 = false;

    /*Service*/
    private int mBindFlag;
    public static Messenger mActivityMessenger;

    static int result;
    private final boolean mFinished = false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActivityMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, SpeechRecognitionService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("Messenger", mActivityMessenger);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        mBindFlag = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ? 0 : Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT;

        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction( TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA );
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CHECK_TTS_DATA: {
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                    Log.d("TTS", "TTS available");
                    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("TTS", "TTS NOT available");
                    Intent promptInstall = new Intent();
                    promptInstall.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(promptInstall);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * MAIN METHOD
     * 
     ******************/

    public void SpeechWhenMotion() {
        while (!mFinished) {
            if (fase0) {
                tts.speak("Initializing", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                fase0 = false;
            }
            else if (fase1) {
                if (result == SpeechRecognitionService.CONTINUE) {
                    tts.speak("Correct", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    mFinished = true;
                }
                else if (result == SpeechRecognitionService.NO_MATCH) {
                    tts.speak("No matching", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("RESULT", String.valueOf(result));
                }
            }
        }
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * SERVICE LINK
     * 
     ******************/

    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.d("SERVICE", "onServiceConnected"); //$NON-NLS-1$

            SpeechRecognitionService.mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = SpeechRecognitionService.MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING;
            try {
                SpeechRecognitionService.mServiceMessenger.send(msg);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.d("SERVICE", "onServiceDisconnected");
            SpeechRecognitionService.mServiceMessenger = null;
        }
    };


    private static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case SpeechRecognitionService.MSG_SPEECH_RESULT:
                    Log.d("MESSENGER", "Message received");
                    result = msg.arg1;
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * IMPLEMENTED METHODS
     * 
     ******************/

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            /*set Language*/
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level
            // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate
            /*Start main method*/
            Log.d("TTS", "Initialized, starting main method");
            SpeechWhenMotion();
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }

    }



    /******************
     * 
     * LIFE CYCLE
     * 
     ******************/

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /*Bind SpeechRecognition service*/
        bindService(new Intent(this, SpeechRecognitionService.class), mServiceConnection, mBindFlag);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        /*Unbind SpeechRecognition service*/
        if (mActivityMessenger != null) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mActivityMessenger = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class SpeechRecognitionService extends Service {

    protected static AudioManager mAudioManager;
    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    public static Messenger mServiceMessenger;

    protected boolean mIsListening;
    protected volatile boolean mIsCountDownOn;
    private static boolean mIsStreamSolo;

    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING = 1;
    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL = 2;
    static final int MSG_SPEECH_RESULT = 3;

    static ArrayList<String> matches;
    static final int CONTINUE = 11;
    static final int NO_MATCH = 12;



    /******************
     * 
     * ONCREATE
     * 
     ******************/

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this));

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());

        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("SERVICE", "onStartCommand");
        MainActivity.mActivityMessenger = intent.getParcelableExtra("Messenger");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * METHODS
     * 
     ******************/

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BIND", "onBind");
        return mServiceMessenger.getBinder();
    }


    /**Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around*/
    protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
            try {
                mServiceMessenger.send(message);
                message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
                mServiceMessenger.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
            }
        }
    };



    public void sendMessageToUI(int result) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_SPEECH_RESULT);
        msg.arg1 = result;
        try {
            MainActivity.mActivityMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * INNER CLASSES/LISTENERS
     * 
     ******************/

    protected static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<SpeechRecognitionService> mtarget;

        IncomingHandler(SpeechRecognitionService target) {
            mtarget = new WeakReference<SpeechRecognitionService>(target);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            final SpeechRecognitionService target = mtarget.get();

            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        /*turn off beep sound*/
                        if (!mIsStreamSolo) {
                            mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                            mIsStreamSolo = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!target.mIsListening) {
                        target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                        target.mIsListening = true;
                        Log.d("SERVICE", "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    }
                    break;

                case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                    if (mIsStreamSolo) {
                        mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                        mIsStreamSolo = false;
                    }
                    target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                    target.mIsListening = false;
                    Log.d(TAG, "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            /*speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore*/
            if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            if (mIsCountDownOn) {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
            mIsListening = false;
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
            try {
                mServiceMessenger.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e) {

            }
            String issue = null;
            if (error == 1) {
                issue = "ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT";
            }
            if (error == 2) {
                issue = "ERROR_NETWORK";
            }
            if (error == 3) {
                issue = "ERROR_AUDIO";
            }
            if (error == 4) {
                issue = "ERROR_SERVER";
            }
            if (error == 5) {
                issue = "ERROR_CLIENT";
            }
            if (error == 6) {
                issue = "ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT";
            }
            if (error == 7) {
                issue = "ERROR_NO_MATCH";
            }
            if (error == 8) {
                issue = "ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY";
            }
            if (error == 9) {
                issue = "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS";
            }
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "error = " + issue); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                mIsCountDownOn = true;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.start();
            }
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            Log.d("SR_LISTENER", "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$

            matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

            if (matches.contains("continue")) {
                MainActivity.fase1 = true;
                sendMessageToUI(CONTINUE);
            }
            else {
                sendMessageToUI(NO_MATCH);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }
    }



    /******************
     * 
     * LIFE CYCLE
     * 
     ******************/

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mIsCountDownOn) {
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null) {
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Log from de debuger:

[image]

As seen, the service listener starts and shows onReadyForSpeech, but next to this the TTS is initialized and the listener stops showing logs even if I speak, that then should show onBeginingOfSpeech

Comment: Create a project with the only line of code above to see if you can get both TTS and Speech Recognizer to work.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen Sorry but I haven't understood you, what do you purpouse to do? At this moment I'm trying to implement the SpeechRecognizer as a service, to be contonuosly running, but it isn't working neither

Comment: If there is a lot of things going on, the TTS or Speech Recognizer may just dies silently. To make sure that there is nothing wrong with TTS and Speech Recognizer just create a project and only initialize TTS and SpeechRecognizer. No fancy graphic or loading other thing.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen What i do now is almost that, first an activity uses the camera to motion detection, when motion has been detected, finishes that activity and starts another with no UI, just requests some commands using TTS and then listens to the user's response. Anyway, tomorrow i'll try what you say and I'll notice you

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen, I tought that it waas working, but after doing what you said, I still have the same problem. I have a simple project with just TTS and SpeechRecognizer, but if I enable TTS, SpeechRecognizer's listener isn't showing the logs of each states, so SpeechRecognizer is not working... how could I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you post the complete code for the simple project. So I can run and see what is wrong.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen, full code posted. I translated few things from spanish to english so if I forgot something excuse me

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen, how is it going? any advances with it?

Comment: You should send START_LISTENING only after onInit is called. So instead of send the listening message in onServiceConnected, send it in onInit.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen, even if I do that, doesn't work. I`ve readed in some other post here on stack that some other people use something related with utterance to wait to speak or something else... do I have to implement that? I need to make this work but is driving me crazy

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen does it work for you doing that?

Comment: I never have problem implementing Speech recognizer and TTS in a service. I do not have time to create your project. Why don't you zip your project and send it to me to test.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen Tell me how can I send you my project please

Comment: Click on my name to get the email.

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen mail sent, now I'll wait till you can check the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `onUtteranceCompletedListener` and send the MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING in `onUtteranceCompleted`.

Comment: I've added the `onUtteranceProgressListener`, but still does not work... I call the `startListening()` method in `onDone` but it does not start the Speech listener to listen to user's voice, in fact, the `MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING` message is not arriving to the service. Have you got any full project which uses these booth TTS and STT to try and see what could be the problem?

Comment: You have to send a message instead of calling startListening(). I have a few projects which have both Speech Recognizer and TTS in a service and never have problem. My minimum target is 2.2 so I did not use onUtteranceProgressListener. Make sure you pass an utteranceId when calling speak otherwise onDone would not be called.

Comment: The onDone is called, I can see the log, so that part is OK. When I say calling startListening() I mean sending the message, this startListening() method is my own method where I send the `MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING ` message. It would be posible you to send me one of your projects, or albeit the part corresponding to the TTS and STT? This way I could see where I'm failing and how can I solve it. Cause i've tryed almost everything and I'm not able to make it work...

Comment: The problem is in your manifest, I could not get your project to build. The service is never launched, change your service android:name to com.....that is full path like MainActivity.

Comment: Even If I do that, continues the same way. I've debuged it and the service gets started, the problem now is that the message doesn't arrive to the service... It would be very helpful for me to have an working example to compare and see whats going wrong

Comment: You have to look at the document for Service. Your Messenger was not done right. Should not use static Messenger. Create a member in MainAcitivity mServiceMessenger and intanstiate it in onServiceConnected and pass back the Main Service handler using msg.replyTo by sending a REGISTER_CLIENT message.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with message sending stuff. I din't know if I did it right, but as I saw that at first times the messages where arriving I thought that it was right... Could you explain a bit more how to do this with an example?